# Is it possible to use ORM methods in a controller without logging in Odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, controller, odoo, odoo-8

I'm sending emails to users with a link inside (to a controller). The link is the next one: *http://localhost/my-controller?my_variable=hello*. To receive the variable *hello*, I've created the next controller:

```
class mail_controller(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/my-controller', type='http')
    def index(self, **args):
        my_variable = args.get('my_variable', False)
        if not my_variable:
            return 'Invalid URL'
        return '<h1>This is the received variable:</h1>' + str(my_variable)
```

Everything works perfect. But now, I want to use some ORM methods. To do that, I will have to do something like this:

```
connection = openerplib.get_connection(hostname='localhost',
                                       database='my_database',
                                       login='my_user',
                                       password='my_pwd', port=8069)
```

I was wondering if is there any way of avoiding this kind of connection to use ORM methods (or other methods declared in the Odoo models). First, because it's not much safe to have the user and the password in plain text, and second, because the parameters of the connection can change easily (for example if I install the module in other database or if the user modifies their password).

Can anyone help me, please? Is there other better controller for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `http.request.env`, which is the same as `self.env` you probably know from model methods.

You can do things like `your_objects = http.request.env['your.model'].search([])` and all other things you normally do with Odoo ORM. Just replace `self.env` with `http.request.env` and you are good to go.

You can read more about `http.request` [in the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/http.html#reference-http-request).

Comment: Great answer @Ludwik! Thank you very much!